# Converting timestamp to real date/time in a array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unix-timestamp

I am generating the following array by:

```
var array = upload.split("\t");

[ '1', 'test', '1511435475', '' ]
[ '1', 'test', '1511435492', '' ]
[ '1', 'test', '1511435511', '' ]
[ '1', 'test', '1511435527', '' ]
[ '2', 'test', '1511435540', '' ]
[ '2', 'test', '1511435551', '' ]
[ '2', 'test', '1511435564', '' ]
```

The third column is a unix timestamp which I want to convert into a usual date/time format using javascript. How do I replace the timestamp in that array or place it in a new array with a usual date/time format?

Comment: What has your research about converting UNIX timestamps in JavaScript revealed? What attempts have you made?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below

Edit : I forgot to do the multiplication by 1000 to convert from unix to javascript timestamp

```
var old_array = [ [ '1', 'test', '1511435475', '' ],[ '1', 'test', '1511435492', '' ],[ '1', 'test', '1511435511', '' ],    [ '1', 'test', '1511435527', '' ], [ '2', 'test', '1511435540', '' ],[ '2', 'test', '1511435551', '' ], [ '2', 'test', '1511435564', '' ] ]
var new_array = old_array.map(function(element){
   var temp = new Date(parseInt(element[2])*1000)
   element[2] = temp.toISOString()
   return element;
})
```

Edit 2 : Since there was a miscommunication regarding the question , This is the new solution

```
 var array = upload.split("\t"); //I am assuming it is simply an array of string  eg. [ '1', 'test', '1511435475', '' ]
  var temp = new Date(parseInt(array [2])*1000)
       array[2] = temp.toISOString();
    // You can console array here to check
```

Comment: var old_array = upload.split("\t"); basically this is the first line that I used now for the code. upload is the updated data but that should be fine actually when I think about it. Unfortunately I get am getting Invalid time value as an error using your snippet.

Comment: String.prototype.split() returns an array of strings .However In the example above , old_array is an array of arrays  . I am not sure how old_array can be the output of a split function ?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I generate the array by using var array = upload.split("\t"); and then I copied it in here by using the console.log function

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs and its unix() method to convert a unix timestamp to a moment object with you can later format as you want: `moment.unix(Number).format()`

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

As for the array converion, look at Array map() function which creates a new array based on a given one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Multiply unix timestamp with 1000 to get Javascript timestamp. Then use, Date constructor to convert into desired date format.

```js
var unixTime = 1511435475;
var javascriptTime = new Date(unixTime*1000);
console.log(javascriptTime.toISOString());
```

```js
var array = [ [ '1', 'test', '1511435475', '' ],[ '1', 'test', '1511435492', '' ],[ '1', 'test', '1511435511', '' ],    [ '1', 'test', '1511435527', '' ], [ '2', 'test', '1511435540', '' ],[ '2', 'test', '1511435551', '' ], [ '2', 'test', '1511435564', '' ] ]
array.forEach(function(arr){
  var timestamp = +arr[2];
  arr[2] = (new Date(timestamp * 1000)).toISOString();
})
console.log(array)
```

Comment: var array = upload.split("\t");
        array.forEach(function(arr){
        var timestamp = +arr[2];
        array[2] = (new Date(timestamp * 1000)).toISOString();
            }) console.log(array)
   This is the code I tried now but it gives back invalid time value at .toISOString(); I am creating my array by splitting the constantly downloaded data

Comment: Please share any of the `arr` here, that is, console.log() its value and share